# Corrupted virtual environments after update to Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, conda, python-3.7

I have recently upgraded my conda distribution to Python 3.7 from Python 3.6 (using the `conda install python=3.7` command).

I didn't realize that this upgrade corrupted all of my existing virtual environments that I created using virtualenv. I naively thought that the virtual environments included all the python libraries needed to run, even if I upgraded my distribution.

If I run 'source venv/bin/activate' I am able to run the virtual environment, but if I try to start python I get an error:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007fff92b5f380 (most recent call first):
Abort trap: 6
```

I think the problem is that the virtualenv libraries link to bin/python3.6, but that folder does not exist anymore. How can I solve this problem? I really don't want to recreate the virtual environments, since some of them took a very long time to build and use libraries that took forever to build from source.

I tried to revert back to conda 3.6, but that failed because there were way too many conflicts.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: why where you using virtualenv instead of conda to create your environments

Comment: Good question. I don't have an answer for that. I have always used virtualenv for managing my virtual environments, and the reason I have conda is only because my very first python install was done using anaconda. Looking back that was a mistake, but I don't know how to revert back to a cleaner environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try cloning the environment to a new one with command:
`conda create --clone cur_env_name --name new_env_name`